# How to reference to a variable that's on a script attached to a prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game at a certain point I spawn an object and then I'm trying to get a variable from that object that I just spawned, but I get the 'NullReferenceException'.

It looks like this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ObjPrefab; //this is my prefab
    private GameObject Obj; //this is my empty object that I will spawn
    private bool isGet = false; //this bool tell me if I arledy got the script
    public ObjPrefabScript OPScript; //this is the script of the prefab

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Obj = Instantiate(ObjPrefab); //here I spawn the object
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isGet)
        {
            OPScript = Obj.GetComponent<ObjPrefabScript>(); //now I take the script, if I haven't done that yet
            isGet = true; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (OPScript.BoolVariable) //here I'm cheking a variable from that script 
            {
                Destroy(Obj); //if it's true, I destroy the object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in this line:

```
 if (OPScript.BoolVariable) //here I'm cheking a variable from that script
```

Answer (score 2):

In such cases make your prefab field of the correct type right away

```
public ObjPrefabScript ObjPrefab;

public ObjPrefabScript OPScriptInstance;

private void Awake()
{
    OPScriptInstance = Instantiate(ObjPrefab);
}
```

this ensures that in the Inspector you already can only reference those objects that actually do have such component attached as a prefab. This already rules out the case that `GetComponent` retuns `null` because the component isn't there.

Further you would need to check for the existence of `Obj` .. you continue to call `Update` every frame even after the object has been destroyed.

```
void Update()
{
    if (OPScriptInstance && OPScriptInstance.BoolVariable)
    {
        Destroy(OPScriptInstance.gameObject);
    }
}
```

additionally you could also disable or even destroy this component as well since it looses its purpose after `OPScriptInstance` has been destroyed and is basically a wasted unnecessary `Update` call.

```
void Update()
{
    if (OPScriptInstance && OPScriptInstance.BoolVariable)
    {
        Destroy(OPScriptInstance.gameObject);
        enabled = false;
        // or even
        Destroy(this); // only destroys this component, not the GameObject it is attached to
    }
}
```

---

In general I would avoid this kind of poll checking every frame.
This component completely looses its entire purpose after the object has been destroyed anyway. So I would rather move the destroying of the object into the `ObjPrefabScript` itself.

Whoever is setting the flag can rather directly `Destroy` it right away instead without the need for any component poll checking the flag all the time.

Comment: Thank you, I changed my code so the prefab destroys itself as you suggested, but now I have an other problem: I want to now if the prefab is destroyed or not, how can I do that?

Comment: `if(!OPScriptInstance) Debug.Log("instance has been destroyed");` e.g. like this ... or have an even on your script where other scripts can attach a listener to

Answer (score 0):

Where you instatiate/spawn your GO, keep a reference of your newly added GO. You can access the variable by `spawnedGO.GetComponent<ScriptName>().publicBoolVariable` or alternatively can add a getter method for your bool variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `isGet = true` isn't a guarantee that `OPScript` was loaded. It only guarantees that the program tried to grab it.

Change

```cs
isGet = true;
```

to

```cs
isGet = OPScript != null;
```

Also, make sure `ObjPrefabScript.BoolVariable` is accessible.